# How to require impersonation on a WCF service and set credentials from within the service?

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-security, impersonation

I have a WCF service in which I am trying to set up a set of credentials so that they will be used not only for the service, but also for all subsequent operations on the NAS.

I currently have set the attribute `[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]` on the method and have set `<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAINUSER" password="PASSWORD"/>` within the service web.config.  Since this is an internal service and I don't want to require special credentials from the consumer I would like to use `<basicHttpBinding>` with `<security mode="None">`.  The issue is that when set this way I receive the error:

```
The contract operation requires Windows identity for automatic impersonation. 
A Windows identity that represents the caller is not provided by
binding 'BasicHttpBinding' for contract.
```

Set as above, the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returned is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE despite having the impersonation directive set in the web.config.  It seems to want the credentials passed from the consumer/client rather than set from within the service.

Is it possible to have the impersonation contained completely within the service rather than relying upon the consumer to send the credentials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but it is not done through any configuration. What you used so far is WCF impersonation which targets only impersonation of client's identity.

What you want is using different accounts (probably based on some logic) for accessing remote storage. First of all it is not very secure way because it requires to store accounts and passwords used to access those resources in some configuration file or registry (or even worse - hard code them). You should run your service with special account created just for your application and this account should have necessary permissions for every resource you need.

Anyway you need to log in [your specific account and impersonate it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx). As I know .NET doesn't have API for log in - you must use interop and call Win API `LogonUser` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming.  I suspected it was related to how I was expecting that impersonation would work.  Would it be possible to create/modify the WindowsIdentity in use and use that within a using() statement to execute the desired portion of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Setting this attribute on your service method:

[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]

means that the service code will impersonate the client's identity. So if you don't want to use the credentials of the calling client (which it seems is the case) then you want to leave this attribute off of your service method.

What it sounds like is that you want your service to run as a specific identity regardless of the the client's identity.

If setting `<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAINUSER" password="PASSWORD"/>`' isn't working you can change the identity of the Application Pool under which your application is running in IIS. This will result in your application running as that identity at all times provided no service methods are set to explicitly require impersonation.